# How an electrical component behave after being exposed to excessive current/voltage?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-fabrication

I wan't to know more about how to recognize a damaged component due to excessive impulse or constant current exposure. Particularly resistors, ceramic/electrolyte capacitors, protective diodes, transistors, voltage regulators. Which of them will behave like an open circuit and which of them like a short circuit? Also where I can find literature about that topic, and how is that usually described in the datasheets?

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from fuses, few (if any) vendors will specify details about this mode of operation. In some designs however knowledge on the failure mode is definitely used eg. as sacrificial components to protect the more expensive ones or to prevent more catastrophic failures. It highly depends on the exact component and the exact cause of failure.

Comment: Semiconductors tend to fail shorted from moderate overloading. Anything is an open circuit if you apply enough current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resistors:

- Causes of Failure: Too much power dissipated resulting in high temperature.
- Physical Changes: They may appear discolored or release some smoke.
- New State: Open circuit or different resistance value.

### Capacitors:

- Causes of Failure: Too high of a voltage for any type or a reverse voltage on a polarized type.
- Physical Changes: Depends on the type of capacitor. Some burn, some explode, some small ceramic caps may not appear different.
- New State: Could be open or short.

### Diodes:

- Causes of Failure: Too much current flowing through the junction, or too much voltage applied in reverse.
- Physical Changes: Larger parts will release their "magic smoke" and may discolor. Smaller parts may not have observable changes.
- New State: Often short.

### Transistors:

- Causes of Failure: Too much current flowing through an device when it is on, too much voltage across a device when it is off, or too much power dissipated when it is in active mode. For a BJT: too much current through the base. For a FET: Too much voltage on the gate. Probably others...
- Physical Changes: Larger parts will release their "magic smoke" and may discolor. Smaller parts may not have observable changes.
- New State: Depends largely on the device type.

Integrated circuits such as voltage regulators should be thought of in terms of their internal components. For typical regulators the point of failure would be the output transistor.

I realize there are a lot of "maybes" and "depends" in the above, but with experience you will be able to tell what is broken just by the smell of it :)

Comment: Transistors and IC's sometimes blow a hole in the ceramic package. I've seen metal (TO-3) transistors that melted/burned a 1cm hole in the top of the case.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. You mention the visual changes, but what about the sound? Are some of the damaged components making any sound? And where I can get some literature about the topic of damaged components?

Comment: The only components I usually get some sound out of are electrolytic capacitors. They "pop" if they explode. If a transistor fails as excitingly as jippie mentions it may make a sound as well. I cannot make a book recommendation as I have not personally read any but I am sure there are some out there. But don't be afraid to learn these more practical lessons by just playing around with components (in a safe environment).

Answer (score 0):

Some components just degrade. I've read, somewhere on diyaudio.com, that repeated exposure of the base-emitter junction to excessive reverse voltage will eventually increase noise level and generally make the transistor worse.